# Windows Event Viewer shows wrong severity for all messages from my service

Tags: c, windows, service, event-log

I'm trying to create my own Windows service in C according to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/the-complete-service-sample). My event message definition file looks like this

EventLogMessages.mc:

```
MessageIdTypedef=DWORD

SeverityNames=(
    Success=0x0:STATUS_SEVERITY_SUCCESS
    Info=0x1:STATUS_SEVERITY_INFO
    Warning=0x2:STATUS_SEVERITY_WARNING
    Error=0x3:STATUS_SEVERITY_ERROR
)

FacilityNames=(
    System=0x0:FACILITY_SYSTEM
    Runtime=0x2:FACILITY_RUNTIME
    Stubs=0x3:FACILITY_STUBS
    Io=0x4:FACILITY_IO_ERROR_CODE
)

LanguageNames=(English=0x409:MSG00409)

; // The following are message definitions.

MessageId=0x1
Severity=Success
Facility=Runtime
SymbolicName=SVCEVENT_STATUS_REPORT
Language=English
Status report: %2.
.

MessageId=0x2
Severity=Error
Facility=System
SymbolicName=SVCEVENT_INIT_SYSCALL_ERROR
Language=English
Essential syscall failed when starting the service: %2.
.

MessageId=0x3
Severity=Error
Facility=Runtime
SymbolicName=SVCEVENT_CUSTOM_ERROR
Language=English
Service-specific error: %2.
.

; // A message file must end with a period on its own line
; // followed by a blank line.
```

It's almost a copy of the sample file from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/sample-mc).

However whenever i compile this file, start the service and open the Event Viewer, i see all messages from my service as "Level: Error", even those that should have lower severity.
[image]

The event IDs and the messages are correct, but the severity is always wrong.

I opened the the generated header file `EventLogMessages.h` and here it seems alright as well.

```
#define SVCEVENT_STATUS_REPORT           ((DWORD)0x00020001L)
```

The upper 2 bits (that indicate severity) are correctly set to 0 - STATUS_SEVERITY_SUCCESS.
But regardless, the event is always displayed wrong.

Anyone has a clue why it's wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figured it out by trial and error.

The severity is in fact only controlled by the 2nd parameter of [ReportEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-reporteventa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and the upper bits of the `messageID` (that comes from the .mc file and goes to the 4th parameter) are totally ignored.

So to send a "warning" event, instead of defining the message properties like

```
MessageId=0x2
Severity=Warning
Facility=Runtime
SymbolicName=SVCEVENT_WARNING
...
```

you need to call the function this way

```
ReportEvent( hEventSource, EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE, 0, SVCEVENT_WARNING, ... );
```

Not sure what message severity is good for then, but it works.